# Is flex items' order animatable?

Tags: jquery, css, animation

On page https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order it says "yes".

While I try it on my own, they won't animate. Did I misunderstand the above page when it says property 'order'  is animatable?

```js
$('.flex-item').click(function() {
  var offset = $(this).css('order') - 3;
  $('.flex-item').each(function() {
    var current = $(this).css('order');
    var checker = current - offset;
    var des;
    if (checker < 1) des = checker + 5;
    else if (checker > 5) des = checker - 5;
    else des = checker;
    $(this).css('order', des);
  });
});
```

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  transition: all 5s ease
}
.flex-item {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  border: solid 1px black;
  transition: all 5s ease
}
.a {
  order: 1;
  background: yellow
}
.b {
  order: 2;
  background: red
}
.c {
  order: 3;
  background: blue
}
.d {
  order: 4;
  background: green
}
.e {
  order: 5;
  background: black
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item a">1</div>
  <div class="flex-item b">2</div>
  <div class="flex-item c">3</div>
  <div class="flex-item d">4</div>
  <div class="flex-item e">5</div>
</div>
```

Besides, from this question of mine you can see that I am confused by jQuery animation and CSS animation. If both are in effect, who is actually governing? And what is the priority rule? That 'animatable' on mdn page is referring to CSS or JavaScript?

Comment: Good question. Would be nice to get a nice transition animation here

Answer (score 0):

Yes. `order` is animatable.

However, in your snippet you change the `order` of all elements, so it may be difficult to see what's happening. Try clicking the last item in the following fiddle:

```js
$('.flex-item').click(function() {
  $(this).css('order', '0');
});
```

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
}
.flex-item {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  border: solid 1px black;
}
.transition > .flex-item {
  transition: all 5s linear;
}
.a {
  order: 1;
  background: yellow;
}
.b {
  order: 2;
  background: red;
}
.c {
  order: 3;
  background: blue;
}
.d {
  order: 4;
  background: green;
}
.e {
  order: 5;
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Click a box. It will be moved to the beginning.</p>
With transition:
<div class="flex-container transition">
  <div class="flex-item a">1</div>
  <div class="flex-item b">2</div>
  <div class="flex-item c">3</div>
  <div class="flex-item d">4</div>
  <div class="flex-item e">5</div>
</div>
With no transition:
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item a">1</div>
  <div class="flex-item b">2</div>
  <div class="flex-item c">3</div>
  <div class="flex-item d">4</div>
  <div class="flex-item e">5</div>
</div>
```

When animated, the clicked item should retrocede, step by step, to the beginning. If there is no animation, it will be moved instantly.

Note Chrome doesn't seem to support it, but works on Firefox.

Comment: I don’t see this working in Chrome 40.0.2214.115 or Firefox 34.0.5

Comment: Does nothing in Safari, on iOS 7 (though Stack Snippets, and JS Fiddle et al are all a bit hit-and-miss in iOS 7 Safari...).

Comment: According to the spec this property is intended to be animatable: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-flexbox/#order-property But it looks like browser support might not be there just yet.

Comment: still does not work as of now (chrome 58.0.3029.110)